# Migrate PHP code from MSSQL to MySQL[duplicated]

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, migration

I currently have a large web application that connects to MSSQL to fetch its data. This web app has hundreds of .php files. I have a new customer, and he doesn't want to use MSSQL, but MySQL instead.

I've searched and found lots of articles on how to migrate data. But that's not my problem. I know how to do that, besides we'll be starting with a blank database, except for a few default catalogs.
Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Likely not what you want to hear, but Id recommend re-writing the app with a server agnostic framework like laravel which can then be configured to use most any database technology so you only have to do this once. Otherwise, you'll have the same issue  when the next customer wants to use Postgres etc..

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not much we can help you here,  as there is no programmative way to convert the php and sql code over mysql. You need to do identify the relevant pieces of code and manually change those

Comment: Emmm okay thanks anyways i appreaciate your help 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrate PHP code from MSSQL to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542449/migrate-php-code-from-mssql-to-mysql)